# Attribute that displays property value in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes, intellisense

I believe I saw somewhere an attribute that, when applied to a class, would show the **value** of a property in intellisense. I'm not talking about XML comments. It looked something like this:

```
[SomeAttribute("Name = '{0}', Age = '{1}'", Name, Age)]
MyClass
```

Anyone know which Attribute I'm talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn’t make sense to “show a value in IntelliSense”, but I guess you mean *in the debugger*. In that case, the attribute you’re looking for is `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = '{Name}', Age = '{Age}'")]
public class XYZ
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}
```

Of course, you can also override the `ToString()` method instead. In the absense of a `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`, the debugger uses `ToString()`. You should use `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` only if you really need the implementation of `ToString()` to be different (and insufficient for debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are not thinking of the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) used while debugging? That has a similar format to the one you have shown, but is used to give a "value" to a class for debugging that is shown in the debug window and when hovering the mouse over an instance.

The format is not the same as a string format like you have, but uses a special syntax:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = '{Name}', Age = '{Age}'")]
MyClass
```

When debugging, this will show the values of the `Name` and `Age` properties of the instance of `MyClass` in the string instead of the type of `MyClass`.